# std map access element while creating new one thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I have a `map<int, Fruit> x`. On one thread I try to read the data of one element `x[10].type`, while on another thread I create a new element `Fruit &new_fruit = x[7]`. Is this thread safe? Since from what I can understand as long as it is not the same key/element it should be fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657249/thread-safety-of-c-std-containers - TLDR - only concurrent reads are safe, and remember that the read of a map can end up writing to it if the element doesnt exist, so always lock is probably the best answer

Comment: To be more specific, reading with `[]` can do a write. Reading with `.find()` (among others) won't do any writing (`[]` will create a node if the key you give is absent, but `.find()` will return `yourMap.end()` if the key is absent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably referring to iterator invalidation, when you say that from what you understand, it's safe as long as you're not reading/writing to the same key from different threads.

However, thread safety doesn't work like that. Unless it is explicitly guaranteed (or proven,) you must assume that this kind of access to a data structure is unsafe. And by "this kind of access" I mean non-synchronized non-`const` access to the data structure and its meta-data from more than one thread.

If you need convincing, just think about the balanced binary search tree (e.g. red-black or AVL tree) that is almost always used to implement a `std::map`. When you insert an element (as `x[7]` can do,) it will re-organize (or "rotate") other nodes, and also will update the calculated heights or number of children in the nodes.

Any non-trivial datastructure/container that doesn't give you guarantees about data races and thread safety *must* be considered as thread-unsafe and protected with external critical sections. Unless *proven* otherwise. Carefully.

Comment: If I had a reference or pointer to one element of the map, would it be safe to read that while something else is writing to another key. Or would I have to make a map of pointers instead?

Comment: @jujumumu: it should be safe, as std::map (and even unordered_map, AFAIK) guarantee stability of the pointers  to values, i.e. the map won't move the values around, unless they are removed/replaced directly.